# Plotting multiple lines in MS Excel

Tags: excel, plot

THis is my dataset

```
           A          I       O     U       X       Y       Z        V
August    52.49     34.20   11.61   0.08    1.59    0.03    0.00    0.00
September 50.09     40.74   7.36    0.53    1.14    0.14    0.00    0.00
October   40.77     44.52   11.63   1.43    1.43    0.21    0.01    0.00
November  46.99     35.05   13.61   1.34    0.99    0.37    1.27    0.40
December  56.65     22.64   13.72   1.56    1.06    0.35    3.13    0.89
January   53.58     23.28   13.17   1.95    1.36    0.38    4.82    1.46
```

I tried using a line plot and the problem is for one column it does the plotting correctly. For every consecutive column it keeps adding up the values and plotting it. how do I overcome this problem?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Thank you Tim for the edit!!!

Comment: Worked fine for me... I took that data and platted it with the normal 2D line plot... My **guess** is that you're using the incorrect plot type...

Comment: Hi John, looks like ur right. But I am still not satisfied with the result. It looks very cluttered. Any ideas as to how to better represent it?

Comment: That **VERY** much depends on what you're trying to accomplish / represent to the user and is probably something more suited to http://superuser.com/, but if you just want it to look less cluttered, maybe try a 3-d line graph....

Comment: Have you tried switching the row / columns?  I find this data is better represented with the months along the axis.